# div not centered in IE but works fine in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css

I know this issue has been discussed a lot and i have read over the other questions and answers but i have not been able to solve this issue. I am using bootstrap and i want to center a div which works in chrome and firefox however in explorer the content is on the right side of the screen. I am unsure of what approach to take in order to correct the position. The css for my page is:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.sRed {
  color: black;
}
u {
  color: red;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 14rem;
}
.jumbotron {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
}
.fa-exclamation-triangle {
  color: red;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
    <div class="container">
      <h1><center><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i><u><span class="sRed">Title</span></u></center></h1>
      <center>
        <h3>Main Content.</h3>

      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have included a fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tvc4tv9L/). Thank you for any help and suggestions

Comment: Not really sure what your doing in your Fiddle. Centering is a lot simpler than that if all that code is to center an element.

Comment: @Ruddy...actually **vertical** centering (when you don't know dimensions) is quite hard. The method used is the optimal one.

Comment: @Paulie_D centering with transform property certainly is not the most optimal way, it's must be used only when height is undefined and when you can't use flexbox. Because transform creates stacking-context layer and creates sub-pixel rendering issues, which is affects quality of text and other things.

Comment: That's what I meant...optimal **in this situation**

Comment: Ok, sorry, it's more like not for you personally, but for other people, who can think by mistake that they must use this method in any situation.

Comment: For the record, Firefox uses unprefixed `transform` properties, and has for a while now, and, considering that the spec for the property is unprefixed, you should *always* include the unprefixed version of any property you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are missing normal transform property (and -ms for old browsers)
http://jsfiddle.net/tvc4tv9L/2/

```
-moz-transform:    translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform:      translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` and `-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to `.jumbotron` for IE9+.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never ever use the `<center>` tags. Use the css equivalent instead: `text-align: center;`
2. You forgot the `-ms-` prefixed translate property.
3. If you don't care about support for IE9 or lower: You can use flexbox for this as well.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  background: black
}

.jumbotron {
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
  <div class="container">
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <h3>Main Content.</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.sRed {
  color: black;
}
u {
  color: red;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 14rem;
}
.jumbotron {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
}

.fa-exclamation-triangle {
  color: red;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
    <div class="container">
      <h1><center><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i><u><span class="sRed">Title</span></u></center></h1>
      <center>
        <h3>Main Content.</h3>

      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, -1 for suggesting a less flexible method than already being used.

Comment: As I wrote, another way (not the best one)